# Unable to invoke AJAX POST request

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, hyperledger-fabric

I am sending Json data with array value.

I am unable to get success with AJAX post request. Can any one help me to resolve this issue.

```
formInfo = "{\"name\":\"raj\",\"empId\":\"1242\",\"contact\":\"177\",\"email\":\"raj@vl.com\",\"fUpload\":\"\"}";
    argsarray =[];
    argsarray[0]="fileupload";
    argsarray[1]= formInfo;

$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:4000/channels/mychannel/chaincodes",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        data: {
            chaincodeName:"changedneww707",
            chaincodeVersion:"v0",
            functionName:"init",
            args:argsarray
        },
        beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MDI5Nzk1ODMsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiQmFycnkiLCJvcmdOYW1lIjoib3JnMiIsImlhdCI6MTUwMjk0MzU4M30.nsZK_T0Gj5yeA7xTuYE0YRcHIyb33mXOTSrll-bOXKE');},
        success: function(res) {
        console.log("Redirecting to Aftemplate");

        },
        error: function(xhr, status){
            console.log("error : " + status);
        }
    });
```

Comment: check the console, if you getting any error.

Comment: In console its printing like "error : error"

Comment: the network console.

Comment: check  error by alert.                                                                            
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(jqXHR.status);
    alert(textStatus);
    alert(errorThrown);
}

Comment: check network tab

Comment: @Kamal  ... in alerts its giving 400  error badrequest

Comment: @Moulali fixed ?

Comment: @Kamal not fixed.. still facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize your JSON

```
data:{  
      chaincodeName:"changedneww707",
      chaincodeVersion:"v0",
      functionName:"init",
      args:JSON.stringify(argsarray)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

For `GET` requests, data field is converted to a query string, if not already a string and appended to the url. Your request type is `POST`, convert your data to string as follows:

```
data:JSON.stringify(yourDataObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 1.0.0 Hyperledger Fabric no longer has capability to work via REST API, there are set of SDK which provides you with ability to interact with peers and invoke chaincodes. These are SDKs:

1. [Java SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java)
2. [Node SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node)
3. [Go SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go)
4. [Python SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-py)

Comment: I'm using node sdk(node_modeule) with fabric samples/balance transfer and from front end by using curl comands i'm using